# Taking the second time derivative of a scalar field

Tags: field-theory, differentiation, mathematics, calculus

Given some scalar field $\phi(x,y,x,t)$, taking its first total derivative we get:
$$\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}$$
or:
$$\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}+\vec{v}\cdot \vec{\nabla}\phi$$
But I'm having a hard time simplifying the second derivative:
$$\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}=
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}\right)
+
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\vec{v}\cdot \vec{\nabla}\phi\right)
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}\right)=
\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial^2 t}+\vec{v}\cdot \vec{\nabla} \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\vec{v}\cdot \vec{\nabla}\phi\right)=\vec{a}\cdot \vec{\nabla}\phi +\vec{v}\cdot \frac{d}{dt}\vec{\nabla}\phi
$$

$$
\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}=
\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial^2 t}
+
\vec{a}\cdot \vec{\nabla}\phi 
+
\vec{v}\cdot\left( \frac{d}{dt}\vec{\nabla}\phi + \vec{\nabla} \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}\right)
$$
Is there a way to simplify this further? I can't manage to simplify the expression:
$$
\vec{v}\cdot\left( \frac{d}{dt}\vec{\nabla}\phi + \vec{\nabla} \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}\right)
$$
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I'm having a hard time simplifying the second derivative:...

> $$
> \frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}=
> \frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial^2 t}
> +
> \vec{a}\cdot \vec{\nabla}\phi 
> +
> \vec{v}\cdot\left( \frac{d}{dt}\vec{\nabla}\phi + \vec{\nabla} \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}\right)
> $$

> Is there a way to simplify this further?

Not really. You can manipulate it a bit more, but I wouldn't call it simplifying...

> I can't manage to simplify the expression:
> $$
> \vec{v}\cdot\left( \frac{d}{dt}\vec{\nabla}\phi + \vec{\nabla} \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}\right)
> $$
> Any help would be greatly appreciated!

If you want to, you could rewrite:
$$
\vec{v}\cdot\left( \frac{d}{dt}\vec{\nabla}\phi + \vec{\nabla} \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}\right)
$$
as
$$
2\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\nabla} \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}
+v_i v_j \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\;,
$$
where the sum over $i$ and $j$ is implied.

But not sure if you think this is more simplified or less simplified...